# adapt height of a div based on width (inversely proportional)

Tags: html, css, height, width

I want to create a responsive layout with a header and footer image that should always be shown and use the full width. Between these two should be the content, with a scrollbar in case it overflows.
The problem is that as I want to use images for the banners, the height of these images depends on the width. This image should make it clear: [illustration](https://scontent-b-mxp.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/10898271_10155049489510517_1622279248770541675_n.jpg?oh=0873d64aa919b318ac4b3f0e989d09e9&oe=55449093)

I found various CSS based solutions, but they either assumed fixed size height of the banners or worked only for static proportions (e.g. http://ansciath.tumblr.com/post/7347495869/css-aspect-ratio ). Also the calc() function of CSS did not help as it doesn't allow the combination of width and height. I know I can do it with JavaScript, but I wanted to know if this is possible without it?

Edit: sample html code

```
<header>
  <img src="testheader.jpeg" />
</header>

<section>
  <div id="content">
    content
  </div>
</section>

<footer>
  <img src="testfooter.jpeg" />
</footer>
```

and the css:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#content {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I dont think it is possible with css as the header, footer height will change so you will need JS to get the dynamic width here is the demo with fixed height http://jsfiddle.net/6tdz0o5g/

Comment: here is jQuery version for dynamic height http://jsfiddle.net/6tdz0o5g/2/

Comment: You might find this to be of use: [How can I set the height of my website to be the same height as the visible browser window, with no vertical scrolling?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35486/how-can-i-set-the-height-of-my-website-to-be-the-same-height-as-the-visible-brow/35505#35505)

Comment: thanks for the js solution, Vitorino Fernandes, i guess i'll use it as it's not possible without js.